# Boolean and String Overloads of the Assignment Operator (C++)

Tags: c++, string, boolean, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I am defining multiple overloads of the **assignment operator** as follows:

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
private:
    bool my_bool;
    int my_int;
    std::string my_string;
public:
    Foo& operator= (bool value);
    Foo& operator= (int value);
    Foo& operator= (const std::string& value);
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
// Assignment Operators.
Foo& Foo::operator= (bool value) {my_bool = value; return *this;}
Foo& Foo::operator= (int value) {my_int = value; return *this;}
Foo& Foo::operator= (const std::string& value) {my_string = value; return *this;}
```

And here's my main.cpp (see the comment marked `SURPRISE`):

```
Foo boolFoo;
Foo intFoo;
Foo stringFoo;

// Reassign values via appropriate assignment operator.
boolFoo = true;                // works...assigned as bool
intFoo = 42;                   // works...assigned as int
stringFoo = "i_am_a_string";   // SURPRISE...assigned as bool, not string

std::string s = "i_am_a_string";
stringFoo = s;                 // works...assigned as string

// works...but awkward
stringFoo = static_cast<std::string>("i_am_a_string");
```

**Question:** Can someone tell me why an uncasted string literal is being evaluated in a boolean context?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Why remove the constructors? I added them to intentionally indicate that a variable can be ***initialized*** via a constructor, and then ***reassigned*** via an assignment operator. (As I've seen in other SO posts, sometimes you need ***both***.)

Comment: I trimmed the code because of [Good questions have a short self contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) and [your code could be significantly shorter and simpler and still reproduce the problem](http://ideone.com/W2nemc).  I didn't read most of your question the first time, because it had _far_ too much code in there, and I guessed (correctly) that most of it was unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Yes, I very much agree in principle and did consider this when adding the constructors to my example. But I'll defer to your judgement here. However, my hope is that anyone that comes across my comment will know to consider the associated contructors as well.

Comment: I don't understand, why would you desire them to consider the associated constructors?  constructors could be relevant to similar questions, but they are completely irrelevant in this question.  If they see constructors, that might make people think that this is related to their constructors.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Thank you for continuing to push. What is now really sinking in for me is that the method signatures `Foo(std::string&)` and `Foo(char *)` are quite different, whether `Foo` is a constructor or any other method. So, I now realize that my gap in understanding really went beyond what I saw happening with the assignment operators (the subject of my posted question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ standard defines overload resolution rules in chapter 13.3, there you find:

> **13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank]**
>
> <sup>2</sup> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> — a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
>
> — a user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

This means that the compiler will prefer a standard conversion sequence from the string literal to `bool` or `int` if available. Now, which standard conversions are relevant? In your case, these two are relevant:

> **4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array]**
>
> <sup>1</sup> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

This conversion turns the string literal, which is of type `const char[N]`, into a `const char*`. The second one is:

> **4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]**
>
> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

That is the reason why the pointer is converted to `bool`. Since a standard conversion sequence exists, the user-defined conversion to `std::string` is not used.

To solve your problem, I suggest you add another overloaded version that takes `const char*` and make it forward the call to the `const std::string&` overload.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! The other lesson for me here is that a string literal maps to `char *` (via `char[N]`), *not* `std::string`.

Comment: @DavidRR: those should be `const char*` and `const char[N]`, but yes.

Answer (score 4):

Daniel is right.

The short answer is that `std::string` is not a built-in type and, as such, doesn't get any magical preferential treatment. And that, unfortunately, the type of a string literal such as `"hi world"` is *not* `std::string`, but a pointer type which more easily converts to the built-in type `bool` than to the "user-defined"<sup>†</sup> type `std::string`.

Basically, the answer is: welcome to C++.

<sup><sup>†</sup> Yes, I know, it's from the *standard* library and, no, it doesn't matter.</sup>

Comment: I think someone downvoted because that last sentence comes off as a little snarky.

Comment: @Mooing: If it's snarky, then it's snarky at C++. If someone is taking _that_ personally then, well, they're beyond my help.

Comment: As the question poster, I'm not at all offended by "welcome to C++." I'm finding C++ to be quite different from Java and C#. With C++, it certainly seems like there are more opportunities to get in trouble...

Comment: Or put another way, the additional flexibility comes with added responsibility.

Comment: You mean: [With great power comes great responsibility](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Responsibility) :)

Comment: Or put another way, "run and hide" :)

Comment: @Lightness: "Run and hide" certainly did occur to me. I didn't volunteer for this new C++ assignment...I was drafted. :-)