# Visual C++ 2010 accepts string for bool in overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (But using the VC++ 2010 build tools), and I have these two overloaded functions (signatures below) defined in a class which I later call in another class that instantiates the first class (also below):

```
Defined in the class:
Node CreateNode(Node *parent,string name,string node_text,bool expects_node = true);
Node CreateNode(Node *parent,string name, string attribute, string value,bool expects_node = true)

Calling these functions in the macro:
Node axis1 = handler->CreateNode(&sparse,"axis","id","trigger_pt");
```

When I make the function call, it calls the first function, not the second! So it treats the second string as a boolean! However, when I add "true" to the function call, it calls the second function as expected. Can anyone explain this? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string literal `"trigger_pt"` is of type "array of 11 `const char`". The compiler considers it better to convert this to a `bool` than to convert it to a `std::string`. The reason is because converting to `bool` only uses standard conversions (array-to-pointer and then pointer to bool), whereas converting to `std::string` requires calling a constructor. A standard conversion sequence is always considered better than a user-defined conversion sequence (involving the conversion constructor).

> When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences (as defined in 13.3.3.1)
>
> - a standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and
> - [...]

You can force it to use the second overload by making that literal a `std::string`:

```
Node axis1 = handler->CreateNode(&sparse,"axis","id",std::string("trigger_pt"));
```

The other alternative is to provide another overload that takes a `const char*`, which will be preferred over the `bool` version. This overload can simply forward to the `std::string` overload.

Comment: Or add a third overload accepting a `const char*`, to make this automatic.

Comment: I sometimes wish for explicit parameters... `void f( explicit const bool b );`. Maybe with C++2100? BTW: Find the complete conversion sequence [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032114/2073257).

Comment: Great answer, I never knew this! I tried your first suggestion and got to the root of the problem because I got the following error: cannot convert parameter 4 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'bool' I don't know if it's an option I need to set or if VS is just this way, but it does not allow me to call member functions (from classes which are part of the solution) with missing optional parameters. So that is why it defaulted to function with 4 parameters... I think I will go with the const char* from now on.