# Taming C++ operator=(bool) overload's hunger for implicitly converting T*

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++20

I have the following overloads:

```cpp
json_variant &operator=(json_variant &&value);
json_variant &operator=(const json_variant &value);
json_variant &operator=(bool value);
json_variant &operator=(double value);
json_variant &operator=(const std::string &value);
json_variant &operator=(std::string &&value);
json_variant &operator=(json_object &&value);
json_variant &operator=(json_array &&value);
```

The following operation:

```cpp
json_variant v;
v = "abc";
```

calls `operator=(bool)` instead of `operator=(const std::string&)`.

Somebody explained that the implicit conversion for `T*` to `bool` takes precedence because native conversions take priority over operator= and constructor type conversions. However, using the `T*` to `bool` conversion is almost *never* the right thing to do in this case.
The result of taking the wrong overload is understandably lethal, and it's a regrettably easy mistake to make.

I can imagine ugly ways to fix it.

```cpp
json_variant &operator=(const char*);
json_variant &operator=(char*);

template <typename U>
json_variant&operator=(U*) {
    static_assert("This probably isn't what you want.");
}
```

That `operator=(bool)` should be so greedy seems like such an ugly behavior that I can't help thinking I've missed something.

Comment: Why this isn't ambiguous: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032044/boolean-and-string-overloads-of-the-assignment-operator-c. I don't think there's a better way than what you proposed (expect you shouldn't need extra `char*` overload).

Comment: Why is `json_variant &operator=(const char*);` ugly?  Isn't that all you need?

Comment: operator=(const char*) is perfectly fine.  But template <typename U> operator=(const U*) is ugly as sin.

Comment: In C++14 and later, you can use [`operator""s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), eg: `v = "abc"s;` which will invoke `operator=(const std::string &)` instead of `operator=(bool)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick and dirty solution that works as far back as C++98 and beyond:

```
struct foo {
  void operator = (bool arg) { }
  void operator = (const void *ptr); // not implemented
};

int main()
{
  foo f;

  f = false; // ok

  f = "abc"; // link time error
}
```

We declare an overload which takes a `const void *` pointer. That is a more specific conversion from `T *` than `bool`, so that overload is selected by the unwanted pointer argument.

But we don't implement this overload, so if it is used, the program won't link.

My above little program builds if I comment out the `f = "abc"` assignmet, and it also builds if I instead comment out the `const void *` overload of the `operator =`, because then the `bool` overload is selected by that assignment.

Comment: you can make it `=delete`, which fails compilation faster: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb54c99af97cb6d0

Comment: Upvote from me, anticipating @MooingDuck's (massive!) improvement :)

Comment: Accepted answer! In conjunction with =`delete` or a pre-C++11 `static_assert` to catch the problem at compile time.

Comment: However with this simple, highly portable approach that compiles with `g++ -ansi -Wall`, we don't have to touch the class declaration if we decide that we want that overload.   The declaration could be shared (verbatim, with no preprocessor-based tweaking) between two projects where one wants the overload and the other doesn't.